# How to Automatically FILL the Fields in Prompt Window pdf to print

Tags: powershell, pdf

I want to convert JPG to PDF without using software packages or LibreOffice.
I use PowerShell, I found the JPG to PDF with MS print to PDF here: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2233896-powershell-convert-jpg-to-pdf-using-pdf-printer
but when running, it shows up window that I have to full name of the file manually. I want to autofill that, but haven't found a way. Hope you guys help me.

i used pass thru but no works. Haven't found any yet

Answer (score -1):

If you are just looking for the input file path, then you can alter that in the code by hard-coding your full path in the `Get-childitem` section. Change the file path to whatever input file path you want along with the file name, you should be good. I have added a comment for your reference on the same line.

```
$scandir="C:\IT Tools\Print to PDF Powershell\Test-JPG"$scanlogdir="C:\IT Tools\Print to PDF Powershell\Logs"
$pdftoprint=""
$printername= "Nitro PDF Creator (Pro 9)"

#Change the file name and file path of the jpg file # Cleanup old pdf files - Change AddDays value as required
Get-ChildItem "$scanbdir\*.jpg" | ? {LastWriteTime -LT (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)} | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false

# Create a Log file $scanlogname
$scanlogname = Join-Path -Path $scanlogdir -ChildPath "$(Get-Date -Format 'MM-dd-yyyy').log"

# Get the List of files in the Directory
echo "$(get-date) - Checking for any scanned pdf files in $scandir" | Out-File -Append $scanlogname

(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName localhost -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "Name='Nitro PDF Creator (Pro 9)'").setdefaultprinter()

Get-ChildItem -Path $scandir -filter "*.jpg" | % {

Start-Process -FilePath $_.VersionInfo.FileName –Verb print

#out-printer -InputObject $scandir\$pdftoprint $printername

"$(get-date) - Printing file - $_ on Printer - $printername" | Out-File -Append $scanlogname

}
```